# How to get protected and public properties only of a type via reflection in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get only the protected and public properties of a type. This is what i'm currently doing

```
var type = typeof(AClass);
var propertyInfo = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
```

but i'll like to filter out only public and protected properties from private and internal properties.

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Get rid of `BindingFlags.Public`.

Comment: @theB I'm sorry i have modified my question, i want to get protected and public properties of the type but not internal and private.

Comment: You should be clear about what you are trying to do in first place rather modifying and invalidating an answer by modifying your post after posting answer.

Comment: @Rahul I'm sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that property contains of get and set methods, and they can have different accessibility (i.e. one can be public and other can be protected etc). Also, either getter or setter can be missing (get-only or set-only properties). To get properties where either get or set methods are protected, you can do this:

```
 typeof(AClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Where(c => c.GetMethod != null && c.GetMethod.IsFamily || c.SetMethod != null && c.SetMethod.IsFamily).ToArray();
```

I've also removed `BindingFlags.Public`, but that is not required - will work fine with it too.

If you want to get protected AND public properties, just modify a bit:

```
 typeof(AClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Where(c => (c.GetMethod != null && (c.GetMethod.IsPublic || c.GetMethod.IsFamily)) || (c.SetMethod != null && (c.SetMethod.IsPublic || c.SetMethod.IsFamily))).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get protected only:

```
       var type = typeof(T);

        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        var protectedOnly = properties.Where(info => info.GetMethod.IsFamily);
```

Comment: Your solution got me on the right track. So i'm voting it up. Apologies for the original confusion. Thanks again.

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

Try This..

```
PropertyInfo[] props = someType.BaseType.GetProperties(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public
    | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
```

It will work for (public + private/protected/internal, static + instance) of a given Type someType (maybe using GetType() to get someType)